# rails form doesn't work postgresDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I say sorry to everyone for my bad english anyway I've a problem with the rail insertion into a DB, I try in every way to insert some data into a PostgresDB but nothing, somebody can help me ?

Reservation Controller : -->

```
def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation_params])
    if @reservation.save
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path, notice: "Registrato !!!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:hotel_id, :user_id, :room_id, :room_number, :price, :channel_id)
  end
```

Routes file: -->

```
devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'reservations#week', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end

  match '/reservations/month', to: 'reservations#month', :as => :month, via: [:get, :post]
  match '/reservations/year', to: 'reservations#year', :as => :year, via: [:get, :post]
  match '/reservations/revenue', to: 'reservations#revenue', :as => :revenue, via: [:get, :post]
  match '/reservations/future', to: 'reservations#future', :as => :future, via: [:get, :post]
  match '/reservations/event', to: 'reservations#event', :as => :event, via: [:get, :post]
  match '/reservations/new', to: 'reservations#new', :as => :new, via: [:get, :post]

  # match 'reservations/month' => 'reservations#month', :as => :reservations_month, :via => :get
  # match 'reservations/year' => 'reservations#year', :as => :reservations_year, :via => :get
  match 'hotels/dashboard' => 'hotels#dashboard', :as => :dashboard, via: [:get, :post]
```

reservation/new file: -->

```
<%= form_for @reservation do |f| %>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
      <%= f.label :pax %>
      <%= f.text_field :pax %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
      <%= f.label :room_number %>
      <%= f.text_field :room_number %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
      <%= f.label :channel_id %>
      <%= f.text_field :channel_id %>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation_params])
```

to:

```
@reservation = Reservation.new( reservation_params )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the problem in this line

```
@reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation_params])
```

the thing is that if you see in your controller you have a method that just permit some params for security that is "reservation_params"

so you just need to change the line for this

```
@reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
```

and it just works.